# If $\{S_n \}$ is a disjoint sequence of subsets of $X$ then $\lim S_n=\varnothing$

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $X$ be a set. Consider a sequence of subsets
> \begin{align}
> \big\{S_n\subseteq X\,\big|\,S_i\cap S_j=\varnothing\ \forall i\ne j \big\}.
> \end{align}
> Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n$ exists and is equal to $\varnothing$.

My proof :

To prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n$ exists, we need to show $\displaystyle\liminf S_n=\limsup S_n.$ Since the direction $\subseteq $ is trivial, we will show the direction $\supseteq$.

By definition, we have
\begin{align}
\limsup S_n\ &=\ \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k\geq n}S_k
\newline \liminf S_n\ &=\ \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \bigcap_{k\geq n}S_k.
\end{align}
Let $x\in\displaystyle \limsup S_n$, then
\begin{align}
\forall n\in\mathbb N,\ x\in\bigcup_{k\geq n}S_k,
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\forall n\in\mathbb N,\ \exists k\geq n: \ x\in S_k.
\end{align}
Here, I wonder how will we use the assumption that the sets $S_n$ are disjoint ? May you give me some hints on this ? Thanks.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin sorry, I just fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $S_n = E_n$ and that this is just a notational mixup, note that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}\exists k \geq n\colon x \in E_k$ implies that $x$ lies in $E_k$ for infinitely many values of $k$ whereas disjointness implies that $x$ lies in at most *one* $E_k$, so no such $x$ exists.

Answer (score 0):

We have that $\text{lim sup } S_n$ is the set of elements which are in an infinite number of $S_n$. As the $S_n$ are disjoint, this directly implies $\text{lim sup } S_n=\emptyset$.